# Watering plants and temperature

Tags: watering, roots, temperature

It seems obvious to not shock roots with hot or cold water when watering, but are there benefits to using water with a certain temperature?

For example, can temperature stimulate root growth or have any benefit at all?

Comment: Soil temperature has an effect on plant growth. You can use water st different temperatures too help regulate soil temperature but it's not very practical except in the case where cooling the soil. Even then your primary concern should be providing appropriate moisture. Don't overwater just to cool. Interesting question hopefully there are some good answers

Comment: Roots although they are the weakest link to a plant are also very adaptable to water temperature.  The ground regulates that quite quickly and yes, the plants need moisture as well as good drainage and no soggy soils.  During high temperatures the best way is to blanket loosely the soil...shade the soil.  Shade the entire plant without causing an enclosed microenvironment...I'd put a big huge fan to blow heat and O2 produced by the plant away to be replaced by CO2 and cooled air from shade.  Think about the difference in the shade of a tree.

Comment: I would like to add that LONG TERM soil temperature has an affect on plant growth, but watering plants from a cold garden hose won't affect them as the temperature change is temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Hot or cold water will not benefit the plant in any way. Water that is hot (even the water in a hose that was left out in the sun all day) can scald the foliage and also harm the roots. While cold water can really damage the plant's roots, especially tropical houseplants. The best temperature is between 62f and 72f (or room temp.). Timing does play a role however. Watering in the morning is the best time. The temperatures are cool and less water will be lost do to evaporation from heat. Not saying you could not do it during the day, try to make sure the water is not hot from leaving the hose out as said before. Or even cold if it comes from a cellar like mine. It tend to be very cold. And in summer I have 90f weather. Do not water to often, for which wet foliage is susceptible to fungus infections.